# Rust, Diesel can't setup rust diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, archlinux, rust-diesel

when i type "diesel setup" it's  it return that the postgres features must be enabled but i installed postgres

full error :
hread 'main' panicked at 'Database url `postgres://localhost:8080/diesel_demo` requires the `postgres` feature but it's not enabled.', diesel_cli/src/database.rs:40:21
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

OS : arch linux

Comment: please paste the the dependencies in Cargo.toml @Joe Esser

Answer (score 0):

when add the diesel dependencies in Cargo.toml, you should enable the postgres features like this:

```
diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }
```

check your dependencies and make sure the postgres feature enabled.